# Corrupted OpenOffice Writer File Viewing in XML

Tags: xml, document, corruption

I have multiple files saved to an external hard drive in order to usually avoid these sorts of problems. This belongs to a file that I'm writing in. Everywhere I have looked has told me that my issue will be in the content.xml and so it appears as when I try to zip and extract it tells me that content.xml is corrupted and/or broken. I have opened it in XML Copy Editor and it matches the error I get when opening in OpenOffice Writer which is 'Read-Error. Format error discovered in the file in sub-document content.xml at 2,58877 (row,col).' XML Copy Editor is 'Error at line 2, column 58878: not well-formed (invalid token).' I am unsure what this means or how to find the column here. Any suggestions are helpful.